# stackoverflow exception in c# when importing a c++ dll

Tags: c#, dllimport, stack-overflow

I have a C# classlibrary project and inside that I have the below method:

```
public string GetPackagestring(string devID, string ConfigName)
{
    //my code here
    string ProgramName="VOT";
    //here I call a c++ Dll function
    packagestring = getparameters(devID, ConfigName, ProgramName);
    //other part of code 
}
```

I Get the Stackoverflow exception in packagestring line when calling the external dll function.

In my project I am importing the DLL as below

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Import DLL
    [DllImport(@"\DLL\testconfigdump.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "getparameters", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public static extern string getparameters(string pumpid, string configname, string progname);
    ...
}
```

Can anyone help me why I am getting the stackoverflow issue?
The message says the current thread is in stackoverflow state..

Comment: You need to provide code that you use to compile the dll, otherwise it's hard to say what's going on.

Comment: Is GetPackageString being called in a loop?

Comment: You have to use a `StringBuilder` in C# instead of `string`. It will be also helpful to provide the code of  `getparameters` in C.